# finger drawing in android

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am using the sufaceview to draw the path as the finger moves over the phone screen. But when i am moving the finger very fast, all the points are not getting registered and I am facing flickering

```
    @Override
public void run() {
    while(running){ 
        running = true;
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawCircle(right, bottom, 2, paint);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        right = event.getX();
        bottom = event.getY();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Could anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance,
Jagan

Answer (score 0):

Start the thread in `onSurfaceCreate()` method.
i,e

```
@Override

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)

{
     //write your code here
}
```

It takes the continuous events.
Prefer this link
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Using-Surface-View-for-Android-1659.php